# How to select coordiante values in xarray that are indexed with a hyphen string?

Tags: python, python-xarray, pypsa

Using PyPSA with the Linopy backend, I getting and xarray object that looks like the following:

```
Variable 'Link-p_nom':
----------------------

Variable labels:
array([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
       26, 27, 28])
Coordinates:
  * Link-ext  (Link-ext) object 'BE0 0 H2 Electrolysis' ... 'BE0 4 battery di...
Attributes:
    binary:   False
```

What I want to do is to filter out e.g. one value or a list of values.

I tried this as it is typically recommended in xarray:
`vars_link.sel(Link-ext="BE0 0 H2 Electrolysis")`

but it gives me the following error:

```
   vars_link.sel(Link-ext="BE0 0 H2 Electrolysis")
                  ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.sel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html) in general supports indexing using a dictonary which you can specify in multiple ways. The `=`-notation is one way. If you specify it using e.g. curly brackets `{...}` you can also use dimension names including special characters like hyphens:

```py
vars_link.sel({"Link-ext":"BE0 0 H2 Electrolysis"})
```

Comment: Amazing! 
This is pypsa syntax but I could then also iterate through aka. select multiple values:
```vars_link.sel({"Link-ext": nodes + " discharger"})``` 
which would build something like:
```vars_link.sel({"Link-ext": ["1 discharger", "2 discharger"]})```

This resulted in:

```
array([24, 25, 26, 27, 28])
Coordinates:
  * Link-ext  (Link-ext) object 'BE0 0 battery discharger' ... 'BE0 4 battery...
Attributes:
    binary:   False
```

Comment: Yes! As long it is a valid Python dictionary that you pass to `.sel(...)` you can choose any method you like to generate the dict. You can as value not only have a single string or list, but also e.g. slices.